# ListView Selection and TextField BackGroundColor

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I've a problem with ListView selection.

I've a TextField drawed on ListView to permit to edit quantity But from iOS5 upgrade (when row selected) TextField results with Blue Background even if I specify red (or other color) background.

Is there a way to solve it or is a iOS5 Bug/Problem?

Thanks in advance

Now I can add ScreenShot...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by managing setBackGroundColor during listview selection (using UIListViewDelegate).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Se ho la gestione del presa ordine su articoli valorizzo la quantità
    if (Config.PresaOrdineSuArticoli == 1 && ![Testata.Spediti isEqualToString:@"S"]){
        //Posso provare ad accedere al controllo e cambiare il background durante la selezione
        [(UITextField *) [[ListaArticoli cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:-4] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
}
```